# Вопрос по индексации таблиц MySql.

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она предназначена для хранения информации о товаре, поле name содержит в себе название товара, например: "Керамогранит Kerama Marazzi SG609400R Амарено коричневый обрезной 60х60см".

На данный момент поле name индексировано BTREE, это видно на скриншоте. Имеет ли смысл индексировать таблицу по этому столбцу если к этой таблице часто выполняются запросы с подобной проверкой `WHERE name LIKE '%Керамогранит%'`?

Как работает индексация по текстовому полю varchar?

Comment: Индекс с LIKE будет работать только если писать так:  `LIKE 'Керамогранит%'`. Если начинать с процента - то не будет

Comment: Т.е. если с '%Керамогранит%' такой индекс бесполезен и его лучше убрать?

Comment: с '%Керамогранит%' индекс нерабоч, а убрать - зависит от того, будут ли возникать запросы  вида LIKE 'Керамогранит%'  или name = 'Керамогранит'

Comment: тут стоит посмотреть в сторону полнотекстового поиска. для мускуля см. `FULLTEXT`/`MATCH`/`AGAINST`

Comment: Игорь Поляков, нет, таких запросов нет. Что значит "индекс нерабоч", т.е. он просто существует и не будет мешать, или может как-то повлиять на скорость?

Comment: Он повлияет на скорость только модификации данных - точнее, замедлит. Скорость выборки не изменится. Если, конечно, оптимизатору вдруг не придёт в голову его использовать (не на показанном запросе, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Лучше длинно-символьные строки не индексировать, это может повлиять на скорость выборки.

Если уж слишком припекло, используй индексацию по сжатому ключу

```
CREATE INDEX name_indx1 ON product(name)
TABLESPACE INDEXES_TABLE_ALL
COMPRESS 1;
```

Так, при повторяющемся компоненте в индексе выигрывает в скорости (Раз B*tree, то выиграет на уровне 1)